# How to set space on left&right of the logo in the actionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, graphical-logo

### Background

I want to show a bitmap on the left side of the title of the activity, in the actionbar (toolbar, to be exact), so I used this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    ...
```

### The problem

Thing is, the logo seems to have too much margin on its left, while the title text is very near the logo itself, so it looks like this:

[image]

This is not symmetrical at all...

This is even worse in case I have a nav drawer:

[image]

### What I've tried

1. I tried other sizes of the icon, plus I tried to use a bitmap instead of a drawable/mipmap resource (and I actually need to use a bitmap anyway), as such:

   ```
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
        int actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actionBarHeight, actionBarHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(0xffff0000);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap));
    }
   ```

But I still got the same result:

[image]

2. I tried to use this:

   ```
    toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
   ```
3. I tried to use this in the xml tag of the toolbar:

   ```
    android:contentInsetLeft="0px"
    android:contentInsetStart="0px"
   ```

I also tried to play with the other values to its right&end (at least to make the spaces equal in size), but they don't seem to affect the logo margins at all.

4. Only thing that seem to help is this:

   ```
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0px"
   ```

But it helps only if there is a navigation-drawer:

[image]

In the case of no navigation drawer, I still see extra space, which makes it look like un-even spaces on the left of the logo compared to on its right. I tried to set this value to be negative, but it doesn't do anything in the case of no nav-drawer.

5. I've also tried to investigate why it has the extra space, using the "layout inspector" tool so that I might be able to force it to have less space, but I couldn't find any padding/margins that will cause this:

[image]

### The question

How do I avoid this behavior? How can I minimize/set the space on the left&right of the logo?

Why does it occur?

Should I just use a custom view instead?

Comment: You have much control on Custom View.

Comment: Can you please show how to mimic the normal one's style, so that users won't notice anything different?  Is there really no other official way to overcome this behavior ? The text is so near the logo, yet the logo is so far from the left...

Comment: This [project](https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample) utilizes the real feature of coordinator layout using its custom view and custom choreography.

Comment: @Enzokie Can you please demonstrate with minimal code ?

Answer (score 4):

> How can I minimize/set the space on the left&right of the logo ?

Use these attributes in your toolbar to handle margins of the toolbar view.

```
        android:layout_marginLeft="-16dp"
        app:titleMarginStart="@dimen/your_required_space"
```

`-16dp`leaves about 4dp space.

The disadvantage of using `layout_marginLeft` is that it does not work well when there is another view before the logo or your custom bitmap. For example, hamburger icon in case of Navigation Drawer, up-caret icon (back-arrow) when child activity is launched or navigation drawer is opened. This happens because the logo gets replaced by such views.

In such case, you can use :

```
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

> Why does it occur?

Maybe, toolbar class uses already set dimensions which the developers think are the standard dimensions and there is no explicit way to alter them.

> Should I just use a custom view instead?

You can use custom views as you've complete control but with custom views, you get custom headaches.

Comment: Have you tested it? Any disadvantages? Also, about custom view, do you know how to make it look native, to look like the normal API ?

Comment: Yes, I've tested this on API 21 and as low as API 16. I've edited my answer stating the disadvantages.

Comment: Interesting. Have +1 for the effort. Please put a screenshot to show how it looks.