# Layout inside Toolbar is shifted to the right

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar

The `LinearLayout` that's been placed inside `Toolbar` is shifted to the right as you can see...

As a result, the `Toolbar` doesn't stack up well with the `TabHost` (which is again implemented with a `Toolbar` in a parent `Fragment`).

- How can I fix it?

---

**Layout sketch (Android Studio)**

[image]

**Actual app**

[image]

---

**Layout Code**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          tools:context="com.android.example">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recview_navigator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/accent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_navigator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_navigator_up"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_before_white_48dp"
                android:tint="@color/recview"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_navigator_save"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_save_white_48dp"
                android:tint="@color/recview"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you're not going to use the `AppBarLayout` or `Toolbar` remove them from layout.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried removing the content insets?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`    
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
...>
```

Answer (score 2):

> The problem

The extra margin space is because of the `toolbar` tag. It has about `16dp` of space by default. It is required, so that icons like hamburger,app_icon or up-caret can be shown.

> How can you fix it?

Well, the hack is to include `android:layout_marginLeft="-16dp"` attribute in the `toolbar` tag, but this can mess up the layout if up-caret(back-button) is shown when a child activity is called or hamburger icon in case of a navigation drawer.

I've written about this earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39957447/3225001).

If you're not going to use the functionality of `toolbar` then it is better to replace the whole `appBarLayout` with the following layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_navigator_up"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_before_white_48dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_navigator_save"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_save_black_48dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```